# What is the memory bus speed supported by my system

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, motherboard

My laptop is [Asus-k52f](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/K52F/specifications/). It's processor is [intel corei3-370M](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/49020/intel-core-i3-370m-processor-3m-cache-2-40-ghz.html).

It has 2GiB RAM. I was thinking to upgrade the memory. According to my findings using `lshw -C memory` this is my systems memory setup.

```
*-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 41
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 2GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1067 MHz (0.9 ns)
          product: HMT325S6BFR8C-H9
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 0
          serial: 0823E0FF
          slot: DIMM0
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1067MHz (0.9ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 1
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 2
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: DIMM2
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 3
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: DIMM3
```

Here is output of `dmidecode -t 16`

```
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0041, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4
```

From the part number I have found the RAM's [spec](https://www.skhynix.com/eolproducts.view.do?pronm=DDR3%20SDRAM&srnm=HMT325S6BFR8C&rk=20&rc=module). 
So, here are my questions,

1. `dmidecode` is saying max. capacity is 16GB but processor can handle upto 8GB and laptop's spec is saying 8GB. So, the limitation here is processor, right?
2. RAM's spec is saying for H9 the bus speed is 1333MHz but `dmidecode` and `lshw` report is saying 1067MHz. There are speed grade of H9 though. Is it motherboard's limitation? How can I find the supported bus speed of my system? What is speed grade of RAM?
3. There are 4 banks but when I opened my laptop there are only 4 ram slots. So, what are the banks?

Comment: It seems I miss the point that the processor support memory types  DDR3 800/1066.

Comment: well, often the motherboard will allow overclocking RAM up to the max bandwidth, though this is unlikely with a OEM laptop. for instance, on ark, my cpu supports DDR4-2666 type memory, with a max bandwidth of 4.16GB/s, so I installed DDR4-4133, and overclocked using the XMP-4140 profile, yielding 2070MHz per channel.  In your case though, I'd recommend just matching what the manufacturer installed initially, especially in terms of Frequency and Voltage.

Comment: Most everything is controlled by the bios code. So you cannot use memory any faster than 1066 or over 8gb as specified by the manufacturer.